# Error when running XSLT with eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xslt-2.0, saxon, xalan

When I use eclipse xsl development tools to run xsl transformation, it reports the following error. But using saxon there is no problem. SIt would be appreciated if some expert can provide possible solution.

```
12:44:14,714 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=null
12:44:14,725 INFO  [main] Main  - java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/endorsed
12:44:14,744 INFO  [main] Main  - launchFile: /gpfs/work01/work/scratch/users/feifan_liu/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching/launch/launch.xml
12:44:14,945 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(tokenize, [variable-ref(rColNames/result-tree), literal-expr(\|)])'.
12:44:14,953 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Could not compile stylesheet
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:843)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:632)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformerHandler(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:918)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.addStylesheet(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:72)
12:44:14,954 FATAL [main] Main  - Error with stylesheet: file:/gpfs/work01/work/scratch/users/feifan_liu/com.nuance.xslt.ahfs/files/acp2detagged.xsl
org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.ConfigurationException: Error with stylesheet: file:/gpfs/work01/work/scratch/users/feifan_liu/com.nuance.xslt.ahfs/files/acp2detagged.xsl
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.addStyleSheet(PipelineDefinition.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.PipelineDefinition.configure(PipelineDefinition.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse seems to use Xalan Java which is an XSLT 1.0 processor and it simply complains about code in your stylesheet using the `tokenize` function which is new in XSLT/XPath 2.0 and that way not supported by Xalan. If you want to use XSLT 2.0 with Java then try [Saxon 9](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/). I don't know details however as to set up Eclipse to use Saxon.